# Objective c - Memory Usage Keeps Increasing - Iphone App

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I have a recursive loop using NSTimer that runs every two seconds and calls a function that calls the setupPhpCall function:

There are 3 NSTimers that run and always hits the setupPhpCall function,
could this be where the memory leakage is happening?

```
-(NSString*)setupPhpCall:(NSString*)requestString :(NSString*)sciptPage{

NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];

// Create your request string with parameter name as defined in PHP file
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.xxxx.co.uk/%@", sciptPage]]];
// set Request Type
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
// Set content-type
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
// Set Request Body
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
// Now send a request and get Response

NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&urlResponse error: &error];
// Log Response
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",response);

return response;

}
```

This is the recursive method thats called using NSTimer:

```
-(void)recurseForumActivity:(NSTimer *)timer{

    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{


        NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lastDate=%@&threadTitle=%@&threadCountry=%@&threadCategory=%@&threadSubCategory=%@&getData=0",lastDateForumActivity,searchThreadTitle, searchThreadCountry, searchThreadCategory, searchThreadSubCategory];
        NSString *response = [self setupPhpCall:myRequestString :@"xxx.php"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if(response.length > 0 && ![response isEqualToString:@"[]"]){

                labelNewForumThreads.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ new threads...", response];







                if(imageviewForumAlert == NULL){
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alert.png"];

                    imageviewForumAlert = [UIImageView new];
                    [viewNav1 addSubview:imageviewForumAlert];
                    imageviewForumAlert.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
                    imageviewForumAlert.image = image;

                    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"imageviewForumAlert":imageviewForumAlert};
                    NSArray *constraint_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-19-[imageviewForumAlert(12)]-19-|"
                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                                      views:viewsDictionary];

                    NSArray *constraint_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-19-[imageviewForumAlert(12)]-19-|"
                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                                      views:viewsDictionary];



                    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_H];
                    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_V];



                }else{
                    imageviewForumAlert.hidden = NO;

                }
                /**NSDictionary *dic = [response JSONValue];
                if((NSNull*)dic != [NSNull null]){

                    labelNewForumThreads.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d new threads...", dic.count];

                }**/

            }else{

                imageviewForumAlert.hidden = YES;


                labelNewForumThreads.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d new threads...", 0];
            }
            /**else{
                labelNewForumThreads.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d new threads...", 0];
            }**/

        });

    });



}
```

### EDIT

In the console i get this error after i have left the app to run for more than one hour:

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x361c0614> { count = 1, contents =
"XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x361c086c> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
```

i have Allocation tool running aswel

[image]

this is the screenshot of allocation tool when the app crashes

[image]

### EDIT

[image]

### EDIT

I have also noticed when starting Instrument Allocations tool my memory usage rapidly shots up quicker, why is this?

Comment: The memory that its shows on xcode is on average going up 1mb per minute

Comment: Start with Instruments, and let it run overnight (on the simulator; might crash on a real device). Then check what you've got in memory.

Comment: i can only run the app on a real device as my simulator don't work is this fine?

Comment: i just got an output in the console : Received memory warning. but the apps still running.

Comment: NSError is leaking in setupPhpCall: don't alloc it but set it to nil.